# Does querying by array input guarantee results will be in same order by default?

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have a stored procedure taking an PL/SQL associative array-valued input, like the following:

```
TYPE IntegerArray is table of Number index by binary_integer;
PROCEDURE GetItems(itemIds in IntegerArray, results out sys_refcursor)
IS BEGIN
Open Results for
select id, name, price from Item where id in (select * from table(itemIds));
END;
```

It's called from C# and the input item ids are in a specific order, which should be retained in the output.
I *can* write C# code which will order the resultant object array `List<(int id,string name,int price)> data` based on the input `List<int> ids` since there is a 1:1 mapping input - output, but what I cannot tell is if I *need* to, or Oracle will automatically return rows in an order based on the input. Is this guaranteed? Does Oracle even *have* a concept of ordering in the input?

Comment: If there's no ORDER BY clause in a SELECT statement, there's no guarantee that data will be returned in any particular order. It is about relational database; rows in tables don't have any order (usually, it is compared to basket full of apples - which apple is "the first"?). Therefore, the only way to return rows in desired order is to apply ORDER BY clause.

Comment: @Littlefoot this proc doesn't know the ordering, it's defined by the input.... which I think answers my question, the calling C# code _will_ need to handle ordering. I'm not even sure a PL/SQL associative array has an ordering to Oracle. If that's the answer, please feel free to provide it as one

Comment: I am a bit surprised that you don't get an error `PL/SQL: ORA-22905: cannot access rows from a non-nested table item`. According to my knowledge `select * from table(itemIds)` works only for nested tables, i.e. without `index by binary_integer` clause.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit yeah. I got this to work but I am not sure why - I was expecting to need an extra step based on SO answers but then it ran so I stopped looking!

Comment: In general item in PL/SQL associative array are ordered, see [PL/SQL Collections and Records](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNPLS/composites.htm#GUID-8060F01F-B53B-48D4-9239-7EA8461C2170): "*Indexes are stored in sort order, not creation order. For string types, sort order is determined by the initialization parameters NLS_SORT and NLS_COMP.*"  However, by using a `SELECT` the order becomes undetermined.

Answer (score 3):

If you have a nested table collection type defined in SQL (you do not, see below):

```sql
CREATE TYPE IntegerList is table of Number;
```

Then you can use it in SQL statements.

When you do:

```sql
SELECT * FROM TABLE(instance_of_integer_list)
```

Then empirical evidence suggests that it will return the values from the collection in order.

(*Note: this is not guaranteed as result sets are non-deterministically ordered when they do not have an `ORDER BY` clause and there may be cases, such as perhaps large arrays on a parallel database, where the empirical evidence for small arrays on a single database instance does not hold and the order may not be maintained.)*

However:

```sql
SELECT id, name, price
FROM   Item
WHERE  id IN (SELECT * FROM TABLE(instance_of_integer_list));
```

Does not guarantee any particular order for the outer query.

If you want to order the outer query based on the collection's order then you will need to use a `JOIN` and an `ORDER BY` clause:

```sql
SELECT i.id, i.name, i.price
FROM   Item i
       INNER JOIN (
         SELECT COLUMN_VALUE AS item,
                ROWNUM AS position
         FROM   TABLE(instance_of_integer_list)
       ) t
       ON i.id = t.item
ORDER BY t.position;
```

---

You do **NOT** have a nested-table collection type (and C# does not support passing nested-table collection types, it only supports PL/SQL associative array types).

You should need to convert your PL/SQL associative array collection to an SQL nested-table collection to be able to use it in SQL:

```sql
CREATE PACKAGE your_package IS
  TYPE IntegerArray IS TABLE OF NUMBER INDEX BY binary_integer;

  FUNCTION map_ids(
    Ids     IN  IntegerArray
  ) RETURN IntegerList PIPELINED;

  PROCEDURE GetItems(
    ItemIds IN  IntegerArray,
    results OUT SYS_REFCURSOR
  );
END;
/

CREATE PACKAGE BODY your_package IS
  FUNCTION map_ids(
    Ids     IN  IntegerArray
  ) RETURN IntegerList PIPELINED
  IS
    v_idx BINARY_INTEGER;
  BEGIN
    IF ids IS NULL THEN
      RETURN;
    END IF;
    v_idx := ids.FIRST;
    WHILE v_idx IS NOT NULL LOOP
      PIPE ROW(ids(v_idx));
      v_idx := ids.NEXT(v_idx);
    END LOOP;
  END;

  PROCEDURE GetItems(
    ItemIds IN  IntegerArray,
    results OUT SYS_REFCURSOR
  )
  IS
  BEGIN
    OPEN Results FOR
      SELECT i.id, i.name, i.price
      FROM   Item i
             INNER JOIN (
               SELECT COLUMN_VALUE AS item,
                      ROWNUM AS position
               FROM   TABLE(map_ids(ItemIds))
             ) t
             ON i.id = t.item
      ORDER BY t.position;
  END;
END;
/
```

Then if the order that the associative array sorts its keys corresponds to the order that you want to display the data then it *should* work *(note: this is untested as I do not have your data, tables or C# application to call the package)*.

Comment: You could also return a RECORD(idx, id) from map_ids so you don't have to join on a sub select with rownum, the idx will be set to the v_idx of your PIPE loop.

Comment: @p3consulting You can do that (and if the index has semantic value then it would be worthwhile); however, 99.9% of the time I see this used the associative array is densely populated with indexes from 1..n and the index has no semantic value so the overheads of creating records may not be worth it in that case. Both methods work and there are different use-cases where they should be applied (and an overlap when you could pick either).

Comment: I assume the order of a nested table is kept within your PL/SQL program. However, when you define a nested table as column type in a table and insert a nested table into it, then the order is not maintained when you select the data later.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit I think it is the difference between an in-memory data structure and a data structure that is persisted into a data file; retrieving the data to a result set is an implementation detail (which is subject to change) but the in-memory data is stored in order and processed in the same order but the on-disk data can be loaded in a different order. Empirical evidence suggests that it behaves that way but, as the answer states, you shouldn't bet that it will always be that way (if you have some application where the order is critical).

Comment: A "nice" proof that nested tables are really unsorted is this example: `IntegerList(1,2,3) = IntegerList(3,2,1)` results in **TRUE**!

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit Technically, that only proves that the `=` operator does not consider order when comparing collections for equality. I don't know of a "nice" way to prove it as the internal workings of the database are mostly undocumented and you need to separate the implementation details (which can change between DB versions) from the theoretical way it should behave.

Comment: Here the Connor McDonald's answer (2019) for PIPELINED functions:
"As it *currently* stands, a pipelined function can be run in parallel only if it takes a ref cursor as input. There is of course no guarantee that this will not change in future.
So you could run on the *assumption* that in *current* releases you will get the rows back in order, but you could never 100% rely on it being the case now and forever more."